# Show error message of github action in pull request

Tags: github-actions

I have a github actions which gives me an "echo". I want this error to be displayed directly in the pull request. Is this possible?

`echo "ERROR: You can only merge to main from dev."`

[image]

i thought github annotations would help

Comment: One possible solution could be to post these errors directly on the PR as comments using GitHub CLI i.e. [`gh pr comment`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_comment). You may prefix these errors with some distinct emoji to highlight their severity e.g. ❌. You need to use this in conjunction with [`failure()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#failure) status check function.

Comment: yes a comment will work nevertheless i dont know how you would use github cli.

Comment: See [Using GitHub CLI in workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows).